# I can't show a popup window below the ImageView that called

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have a ListView of items, each item have an ImageView by clicking on it displays a PopupWindow. The problem is I can not show the window below the ImageView that called. The OnClickListener of the ImageView that call the pw is implemented inside getView() method of my listadapter class.

How I can do to show the pw below the respective ImageView?

ListView

[image]

I tried to do it using this code, but it did not work. onGlobalLayout() is never called.

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        ...

        // ImageView that show the PopupWindow
        holder.menuOverflow = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iv_menu_overflow_item_listview_seccion);
        holder.menuOverflow.setTag(position);
        holder.menuOverflow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                ViewTreeObserver vto = (holder.menuOverflow).getViewTreeObserver();
                vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        y = (int) (holder.menuOverflow).getY();
                    }
                });

                ...

                // Show the PopupWindow
                pw.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.RIGHT, 0, y);

                // Animation
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.grow_from_top);
                anim.setDuration(100);
                popupView.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        });

        return row;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved by me:**

```
int[] _location = new int[2];

// Point (x, y) stored in array _location
// _location[0] = x, _location[1] = y.
v.getLocationOnScreen(_location);

//Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
Point p = new Point();
p.x = _location[0];
p.y = _location[1];

int OFFSET_Y = 30;

// muestra la popup window
pw.showAtLocation(activity.findViewById(R.id.sliding_panel_layout), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x, p.y + OFFSET_Y);
```